# Mail.app stopped showing To: recipients in my header

Tags: mac, mail.app, email

All of a sudden Mail.app is no longer showing in the header who is receiving the email, be it a group send or even an individual (me).  It is there but you have to scroll over that line to see the names. They just are not showing like they used to. How do I resolve this so the recipients are always seen?

Comment: Check your font color settings

Answer (score 2):

I have the same intermittent problem. So far, the only solution I've found is to reboot my Mac. Cycling the Mail app doesn't work. (MacBook Air, MacOS 10.9.4)